# preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '/' in

Tags: php, regex

I am currently experiencing a problem with regex although it has everything it needs, is there a regex lenght limit? Any help would be appreciated

```
$possible_tags_in_regex = "/(<b>|<\/b>|<i>|<\/i>|<u>|<\/u>|<tt>|<\/tt>|<font size=[1-7]>|<font color=#[a-fA-F0-9]>|<\/font>)*/";
            // Add possible tags between every character in a string
            $regex = implode($possible_tags_in_regex, str_split($regex));
            $regex = $possible_tags_in_regex.$regex.$possible_tags_in_regex;

            // Format every regex every match with given tags
            if (preg_match_all($regex, $input, $to_be_replaced)) {
```

Comment: what's up with that? why go through all that trouble if you want to strip all that. Why not just use `strip_tags()` with options?

Comment: Plus, the `<font>` tag is deprecated/obsolete https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font. You're probably stuck with using legacy code somewhere and having to replace all that, correct?

Comment: Striping tags wont help with my solution. Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your full pattern needs delimiters but you are adding them at the beginning and then imploding and concatenating, so you end up with many.  Remove the delimiters from `$possible_tags_in_regex` and add them at the end:

```
$possible_tags_in_regex = "(<b>|<\/b>|<i>|<\/i>|<u>|<\/u>|<tt>|<\/tt>|<font size=[1-7]>|<font color=#[a-fA-F0-9]>|<\/font>)*";
// Add possible tags between every character in a string
$regex = implode($possible_tags_in_regex, str_split($regex));
$regex = "/$possible_tags_in_regex.$regex.$possible_tags_in_regex/";
```

But you can eliminate all of the escaping by using something that won't be in the pattern such as `~`:

```
$possible_tags_in_regex = "(<b>|</b>|<i>|</i>|<u>|</u>|<tt>|</tt>|<font size=[1-7]>|<font color=#[a-fA-F0-9]>|</font>)*";
// Add possible tags between every character in a string
$regex = implode($possible_tags_in_regex, str_split($regex));
$regex = "~$possible_tags_in_regex.$regex.$possible_tags_in_regex~";
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly :)